# Using Google Fusion Tables Markers with Google Places

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm looking for a way to merge Google Fusion Table Data with Google Places. In essence, if I want to find out points of interest around a particular location (which comes from a Google Fusion Table), is there a way of doing it?

I think it has something to do with the Radius of the two API's (Google Fusion API and Google Places API), but I am not sure if this is possible.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on one of the Fusion Tables markers, you can capture the lat/lon coordinate of the marker by adding a click listener to the layer:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent

You can then use the lat/lon object to issue a Places API search:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches